# Minion Pro problem with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

The following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
   \[ a = \sqrt{ b } \]
\end{document}
```

is compiled by LuaLaTeX as

[image]

Why is that?
Minion Pro .otf from Adobe Reader distribution is installed system-wide, TeXLive 2016 is fully updated, OS is openSUSE Tumbleweed.

**update**: out of academic interest I have downloaded a pirated copy of Minion Math, v 1.021, to obtain a similar result with `\setmathfont{Minion Math}`:

[image]

According to the explanations below the behaviour with Minion Pro is to be expected, the behaviour with Minion Math speaks of the faulty font. The question can be closed, I suppose.

Comment: you can only use a font with an opentype math table as `\setmainfont` a general text font will not work, as you see.

Comment: There is an OpenType math font called [Minion Math](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html). Do be aware, though, that it's not free of charge.

Comment: @David Carlisle Please see the update.

Comment: @Mico: you're right that it's not free: it's expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use XeLaTeX you can use the `mathspec` package.  Keep in mind that if you want to redistribute documents with embedded Minion Pro there are [license issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17556).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
\[ a = \sqrt{ b } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could also use the `mathastext` package.  This approach also works with LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
\[ a = \sqrt{ b } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or, if you own a copy of [Minion Math](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html), use that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Minion Math}
\begin{document}
\[ a = \sqrt{ b } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: $1,600 + €600 = wow.

Comment: @JPi No, Minion Pro is bundled with Adobe Reader and the Basic Set of Minion Math is »only« 218.96 €.

Comment: Thanks Henri.  But that's ignoring the license issues that you mention and only using the basic set, neither of which I could do.  So no Minions for me: I'll have to stick with Gru instead.  ;-)

Comment: @JPi Well, these license issues only apply upon redistribution of a PDF with Minion Pro embedded.  Here I'm only rendering the font and put the resulting rendering online.  If that wouldn't be allowed one couldn't post screenshots of anything containing Minion Pro online.  Also if you own Adobe Illustrator or Adobe InDesign you *can* embed the Minion Pro shipped with these.

Comment: Thanks Henri.  What you did is obviously ok.  I'm just thinking of writing a paper and putting a pdf on my website.   It appears that Minion Pro permits print and preview embedding, but whether that's true for fonts that one extracts from Adobe Reader is unclear to me.